# How do I disable a fieldsset using a variable instead of the "disable" word

Tags: reactjs, fieldset, isenabled

I learn React JavaScript and now I have this problem.

Reading the [w3schools about fieldsset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_fieldset_disabled)

I wanted in this code to use the `currentEditableFile`  if it's true to set fieldset = enabled but it's not working using the ternary as you see here:

```
<fieldset className={classes.tagssList} {currentEditableFile ? enabled: disabled}>
        <legend>Select Tags to include</legend>
        {tagsList.map(skill => (
            <button
                className="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                disabled={false}
                key={skill}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => (currentEditableFile ? onSaveTag(skill) : null)}
            >
                {skill}
            </button>
        ))}
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way. Set the value of `disabled` equal to `!currentEditableFile`, which means if the `currentEditableFile` is `true`, `disabled` on the `fieldset` will be `false`.

```
<fieldset className={classes.tagssList} disabled={!currentEditableFile}>
        <legend>Select Tags to include</legend>
        {tagsList.map(skill => (
            <button
                className="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                disabled={false}
                key={skill}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => (currentEditableFile ? onSaveTag(skill) : null)}
            >
                {skill}
            </button>
        ))}
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use it as below:

```
<fieldset disabled={!currentEditableFile} >
```

Please check the [working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-worker-903cu?file=/src/App.js)